# How to prevent 36k x 36k x 36k permutations to be calculated

Tags: python, math, fibonacci

I have a nice planning exercise, that I just can't get my head around (except for brute force, which is too big to handle). We are organizing a golf trip for 12 persons. We play 4 days of golf. With 3 flights every day. (so 12 flights in total).

We want to:

- maximize the number of unique players that play each other in a flight,
- but also want to minimize the number of double occurences (2 players playing each other more than once).

Since with 12 players and 4 players per flight I can roughly create 36k player combinations per flight per day, it becomes pretty compute intense. Is there any smarter way to solve this? My gut feeling says fibonacci can help out, but not sure how exactly.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import random
import itertools
import pandas as pd    

def make_player_combi(day):
    player_combis = []
    for flight in day:
        #print flight
        for c in itertools.combinations(flight,2):
            combi = list(sorted(c))
            player_combis.append('-'.join(combi))
    return player_combis

def make_score(a,b,c):
    df = pd.DataFrame(a + b + c,columns=['player_combi'])['player_combi']
    combi_counts = df.value_counts()
    pairs_playing = len(combi_counts)
    double_plays  = combi_counts.value_counts().sort_index()
    return pairs_playing, double_plays

players = ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J','K','L']

available_players = players[:]
n = 0
combinations_per_day = []

for players_in_flight_1 in itertools.combinations(players,4):
    available_players_flight_1 = players[:]
    available_players_flight_2 = players[:]
    available_players_flight_3 = players[:]

    for player in players_in_flight_1:
        # players in flight1 can no longer be used in flight 2 or 3
        available_players_flight_2.remove(player)
        available_players_flight_3.remove(player)


    for players_in_flight_2 in itertools.combinations(available_players_flight_2,4):
        players_in_flight_3 = available_players_flight_3[:]
        for player in players_in_flight_2:
            players_in_flight_3.remove(player)
        n = n + 1
        print str(n), players_in_flight_1,players_in_flight_2,tuple(players_in_flight_3)
        combinations_per_day.append([players_in_flight_1,players_in_flight_2,tuple(players_in_flight_3)])

n_max = 100   # limit to 100 entries max per day to save calculations
winning_list = []
max_score = 0
for day_1 in range(0,len(combinations_per_day[0:n_max])):
    print day_1
    for day_2 in range(0,len(combinations_per_day[0:n_max])):
        for day_3 in range(0,len(combinations_per_day[0:n_max])):
            a = make_player_combi(combinations_per_day[day_1])
            b = make_player_combi(combinations_per_day[day_2])

            x,y = make_score(a,b,c)
            if x >= max_score:
                max_score = x
                my_result = {'pairs_playing'  : x,
                             'double_plays'   : y,
                             'max_day_1'      : day_1,
                             'max_day_2'      : day_2,
                             'max_day_3'      : day_3
                             }
                winning_list.append(my_result)
```

Comment: a comment on the mathematics: for a single flight one has `Multinomial[12;4,4,4] = 34650` possibilities. For 12 flights yone can pick 12 times out of those possibilities with repetition. That makes [`Binomial[34650 + 12 - 1; 12]`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Binomial%5B34650+%2B+12+-+1,+12%5D) possibilities to set up the 12 flights. Way too much for brute-force ;-)

Comment: My first guess is that this could be phrased as an integer programming problem. Integer programming is a variety of constrained optimization in which the solution must be found in integers. There are various packages to solve such problems. I have used the free software GLPK for related problems and it has worked well for me. You will need to express your problem in a domain-specific language, which GPLK then processes. It is typically much, much simpler to express the problem than it is to find the solution, so that's a big win.

Comment: Can you spell out what you mean by "maximize the number of unique players that play each other in a flight" ? I don't understand. Also, do I understand correctly that you choose a new team of 4 for every flight? or do you choose new teams only every day? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Robert... I want as many players as possible to play each other during the tournament (for the social effect)...  There are three teams formed every day that each goes out for one flight...

Comment: The state of your scheduling is given by 12 (=number of flights) 12-tuples `(i_1, ..., i_12)`, where the `i`'s are in `1,2,3` (according to whether they play in group 1,2 or 3). In order to apply optimization, you need to translate your constraint into something mathematical based on the state.

Answer (score 0):

I chose the suboptimal ( but good enough) solution by running 5 mio samples and taking the lowest outcome...  Thanks all for thinking along

Answer (score 0):

You can brute-force this by eliminating symmetries. Let's call the 12 players `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l`, write a flight with 4 players concatenated together: `degj`, and a day's schedule with the three flights: eg. `abcd-efgh-ijkl`.

The first day's flights are arbitrary: say the 3 flights are `abcd-efgh-ijkl`.

On the second and third day, you have fewer than (12 choose 4) * (8 choose 4) possibilities, because that counts each distinct schedule 6 times. For example, `abcd-efgh-ijkl`, `efgh-abcd-ijkl` and `ijkl-efgh-abcd` are all counted as separate, but they are essentially the same. In fact, you have (12 choose 4) * (8 choose 4) / 6 = 5775 different schedules.

Overall, this gives you 5775 * 5775 = 33350625, a manageable 33 million to check.

We can do a little better: we might as well assume that day 2 and day 3 schedules are different, and not count schedules that are the same but day 2 and day 3's are swapped over. This gives us another factor of very almost 2.

Here's code that does all that:

```
import itertools
import collections

# schedules generates all possible schedules for a given day, up
# to symmetry.
def schedules(players):
    for c in itertools.combinations(players, 4):
        for d in itertools.combinations(players, 4):
            if set(c) & set(d):
                continue
            e = set(players) - set(c) - set(d)
            sc = ''.join(sorted(c))
            sd = ''.join(sorted(d))
            se = ''.join(sorted(e))
            if sc < sd < se:
                yield sc, sd, se

# all_schedules generates all possible (different up to symmetry) schedules for
# the three days.
def all_schedules(players):
    s = list(schedules(players))
    d1 = s[0]
    for d2, d3 in itertools.combinations(s, 2):
        yield d1, d2, d3

# pcount returns a Counter that records how often each pair
# of players play each other.
def pcount(*days):
    players = collections.Counter()
    for d in days:
        for flight in d:
            for p1, p2 in itertools.combinations(flight, 2):
                players[p1+p2] += 1
    return players

def score(*days):
    p = pcount(*days)
    return len(p), sum(-1 for v in p.itervalues() if v > 1)

best = None
for days in all_schedules('abcdefghijkl'):
    s = score(*days)
    if s > best:
        best = s
        print days, s
```

It still takes some time to run (about 10-15 minutes on my computer), and produces this as the last line of output:

```
abcd-efgh-ijkl  abei-cfgj-dhkl  abhj-cekl-dfgi (48, -3)
```

That means there's 48 unique pairings over the three days, and there's 3 pairs who play each other more than once (`ab`, `fg` and `kl`).

Note that each of the three pairs who play each other more than once play each other on every day. That's unfortunate, and probably means you need to tweak your idea of how to score schedules. For example, excluding schedules where the same pair plays more than twice, and taking the soft-min of the number of players each player sees, gives this solution:

```
abcd-efgh-ijkl  abei-cfgj-dhkl  acfk-begl-dhij
```

This has 45 unique pairings, and 9 pairs that play each other more than once. But every player meets at least 7 different players and might be preferable in practice to the "optimal" solution above.